# Sometimes calling driver.get using the firefox driver in Selenium python results in an error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a bot that cycles through the links of multiple sites. Sometimes at the next loop the transition is not performed and an error is generated
`driver.get("https://wmrfast.com/serfingnew.php") AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'`

My firefox driver configuration class

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Browser:
    def __init__(self, is_headless=False):
        self.driver = None
        self.options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        self.options.headless = is_headless
        self.options.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'ru')
        self.options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
        self.options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
        self.options.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)

    def open_browser(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.options)
        self.driver = driver
        return driver
```

My start_view_website method where exception throws

```
    def start_view_website(self, driver):
        print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} " +
              f"{strings['view_web'][self.lan]}"
              )
        driver.get("https://wmrfast.com/serfingnew.php")
        while driver.current_url != "https://wmrfast.com/serfingnew.php":
            time.sleep(1)
        website_list = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "no_active_link")
        if len(website_list) == 0:
            print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} " +
                  f"{strings['nothing_watch_or_view'][self.lan]}")
            return driver
        for i in website_list:
            try:
                a = i.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "serf_hash")[0]
                price_span, time_span = i.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "clickprice")
                earned_money = float(price_span.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
                time_sleep = int(time_span.get_attribute('innerHTML').split()[0]) + random.randint(3, 5)
                a.click()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}{e}{bcolors.ENDC}")
                continue

            for j in range(5):
                if len(driver.window_handles) < 2:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue
                else:
                    break

            if len(driver.window_handles) < 2:
                continue

            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            time.sleep(time_sleep)
            self.total_earned_money += earned_money
            print(
                f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}{datetime.datetime.now()} " +
                f"{strings['earned'][self.lan]}: " +
                f"{round(earned_money, 5)}, {strings['total'][self.lan]}: " +
                f"{round(self.total_earned_money, 5)}{bcolors.ENDC}"
                )
            for handle in driver.window_handles[1:]:
                driver.switch_to.window(handle)
                driver.close()

            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            time.sleep(3)

        return driver
```

My main class with cycle

```
def main():
    settings = Settings()
    wmr_fast = WMRFast(settings)
    driver = wmr_fast.log_in()
    while True:
        driver = wmr_fast.start_watch_youtube(driver)
        time_sleep = random.randint(0, 300)
        print(f'{datetime.datetime.now()} sleep {time_sleep} seconds')
        time.sleep(time_sleep)

        driver = wmr_fast.start_view_website(driver)
        time_sleep = random.randint(0, 300)
        print(f'{datetime.datetime.now()} sleep {time_sleep} seconds')
        time.sleep(time_sleep)
```

What could the problem be related to?

I tried to understand why this happens using a debugger but didn't get anything useful